# How to stream/print the several last appended data from a table in SQL Server using python?

Tags: python, sql-server, streaming

I have a table in my SQL Server that is being updated every minute.
Currently, I get the data from my table using this lines of code:

```
conn = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, "tempdb")

def print_table():
    cursor = conn.cursor(as_dict=True)

    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM EmotionDisturbances WHERE name=%s', 'John Doe')
    for row in cursor:
        #Show the data:
        print("rate=%d, emotion=%s" % (row['rate'], row['emotion']))

    conn.close()
```

In my application, I run this the function every 10 seconds.
How do I update the function so that I only print the last appended data from my table?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an auto-incrementing index in column `id` you'd do:

```
SELECT * FROM EmotionDisturbances WHERE name = % ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

EDIT: If you want all data that was added after a certain time, then you'll need to migrate your schema to have a `created` date column if it doesn't have one already, then you can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM EmotionDisturbances
WHERE name = % AND created >= DATEADD(second, -10, GETDATE())
```

This would get all of the records created over the last 10 seconds, since you said this function runs every 10 seconds.

Comment: what if I don't know how many data I've appended to my table? And I want all those data instead of the last one? I think I need to update my question

Comment: @SaberAlex I updated my answer with an edit to address what I think you meant.

Comment: Is it possible to use cursor object instead modifying the SQL QUERY? @mVChr